# what is the better way to store a single record against multiple rows in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Hi I am new to mysql and java aswell. I want to store a jpeg files and hash values of small chunks of file. I have stored the hash values of small chunks(100s in number) and now want to store the jpeg file also against these small chunks. My question is do I need to store the file again and again for each record or is it possible to save file once and link it to the records related to the file? if so then also please guide me that how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but if understand you correctly this is what I would do.

One table (say tblJpgs) with data about the jpg-file, maybe the path and the filename as suggested by Naved and additionally a description and whatever can be useful info about the file. In this table there will be one row per jpg-file and each row will have a unique id.

Then you will have another table (say tblChunks) for all the chunks. There should be a column for connecting each row with a tblJpgs.id. Then there is of course a column with the chunk itself. In this table there will be one row for each chunk, but there will be many rows for one jpg-file.

In this way you will only save the information in one place, which is very central in database  structures. Storing the jpg-file or the path and filename for it in each row with the chunks would be against this fundamental database structure and should therefore be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the file on the machine and store its path in the database.
Suppose you are having 1 field (say imagePath) in the table which takes **"varchar"** data. You can store the path of the image there and retrieve the image at runtime. By doing this, you can avoid saving same file multiple times. However, it will override the images having same name but different data. For that you have to use Primary key to append to the name of the file. I hope it will help you to understand.